# how to write jpql query with like operator

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How to write below sql query in JPQL in java class

```sql
select e.emp_id, e.emp_name
from emp e 
left outer join dept on e.dept_id = d.dept_id and upper(d.dept_name) like upper('%dev%')
```

I have tried below it doesn't work for me. I need after like keyword how to write with two percentile and parameter name

```java
@Query(value = "select e.emp_id,e.emp_name from emp e left outer join dept on e.dept_id= d.dept_id and upper(d.dept_name)  like upper(%:deptName%), nativeQuery = true)
List<Employee> searchAllEmployees(@Param("deptName")String deptName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have the following `Employee` entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Employee
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "emp_id")
   Long id;

   @Column(name = "emp_name")
   String name;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
   Department department;
}

@Entity
public class Department
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "dept_id")
   Long id;

   @Column(name = "dept_name")
   String name;
}
```

you can write the following jpql:

```java
@Query("select e from Employee e left join e.department d where upper(d.name) like '%' || upper(:deptName ) || '%'")
List<Employee> searchAllEmployees(@Param("deptName")String deptName);
```

See also [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-like-predicate) section of hibernate documentation.